# Error in deleting a trigger in Production: Invalid type: Schema.sObject

Tags: trigger, delete, destructivechanges.xml

Using destructive package in workbench, I am trying to delete a custom trigger (not Managed) from Production built on Managed package object "Question" and I am getting the error:

> Invalid type: Schema.Question

Please let me know what the error exactly mean?

```
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">

    <types>
        <members>mytriggername</members>
        <name>ApexTrigger</name>
    </types>

    <types>
        <members>mytriggertestclass</members>
        <name>ApexClass</name>
    </types>

    <version>41.0</version>

</Package>
```

Comment: Suggest you post your destructive changes XML. Does it include an attempt to delete the object too?

Comment: Hi Keith, added the code. No, I am not trying to delete the object in anyway.

Comment: Thanks. Very weird. Exactly where do you see the error appear? Is it's in the middle of some other information add that to the question too.

Comment: After a test run deploy is completed in workbench I get this as a failure with the message “invalid type: Schema.Question